# Increasing a counter variable through if statement

Tags: google-apps-script, counter

I am trying to create an if statement that sequences through an array, and increases a counter variable by 1 each time the item in the array is "yes". The array includes 10 items that are either "yes" or "no".

```
var testArray = ["yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no"]
var tCounter = 0
function topicCounter() {
for (i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++)
    if testArray(i) = "yes"
       tCounter += 1
```

Comment: You might want to learn the differences between  function call`()` and property call `[]` and assignment operator`=` and comparison operators `==`/`===`

Comment: I wasn't sure, whether `google-apps-script` modified basic javascript syntax at first (never used it), but reading into it, no, it doesn't. Please read a basic javascript tutorial (probably excluding ES6+ features, maybe there are specific tutorials for `google-apps-script`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was just a type mistake, instead of = you should use === when doing a comparison and to access a array by index you should use [].

```
var testArray = ["yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no","yes","no"]
var tCounter = 0
function topicCounter() {
for (i = 0; i < testArray.length; i++)
    if (testArray[i] === "yes"){
       tCounter += 1
    }
```

One tip, avoid using var to declare variables, it is a bad practice, it is better if you use let or const.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to increment. Just filter your array to count the number of  `yes` values:

```
const tCounter = testArray.filter(item => item === 'yes').length
```

Comment: Arrow functions are not supported in apps script yet.